# Every admin only can see his uploaded images im editor

Tags: images

We have a strange problem in Wordpress. Since many months every admin can see only his own uploaded images in the classic editor, when clicking on "Add Media".

In the WP dashboard under Media every admin can see every uploaded image on our server, but it isn't possible easily add/change a thumbnail or with "Add Media" I can see only my uploaded files.

We have tried to set in FTP to set the file permission on 775 in every subfolder in /uploads/.